# How do i remove the last part of an address after the forward slash?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple problem that has been aluding me for a couple of hours. I am basically getting strings in the following format from a server. all i need to do is remove the last part. So for example:

AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD

The result would be:

AAA\BBB\CCC

Another example:

AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD\EEE

The result would be:

AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD

Can you help me? Thank you.

```
$host_attr = $host_attr.replace('`n', '')
write-host "host_attr: " $host_attr
$host_attr = $host_attr.ToCharArray()
[Array]::Reverse($host_attr) 
$host_attr = -join $host_attr
$domanNameDump, $host_attr  = $host_attr.split('\\', 3) 
$host_attr = $host_attr.ToCharArray()
[Array]::Reverse($host_attr)
$host_attr = -join $host_attr
write-host "host_attr: " $host_attr
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-Replace` or `Split-Path` to effectively drop the characters beginning with the final `\`.

**Replace Operator Solution:**

```
$s = "AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD\EEE"
$s -Replace "(.*)\\.*",'$1'
```

**Split-Path Solution:**

```
$s = "AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD\EEE"
Split-Path -Path $s
```

**Explanation:**

The `-Replace` operator uses a regex pattern to find a match and replaces with any value specified. In this case, we use `$1` because it represents capture group 1 (`(.*)`) in the regex `(.*)\\.*`. `.*` is a greedy match of all characters. `\` requires an escape in regex, which is why the pattern contains `\\`. The final `.*` just matches the remaining characters after the last `\` so that they are replaced. The order of `(.*)\\` is important so that the greedy match will stop at the last `\` character found. See [Replacement Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#replacement-operator) for more information.

Since `Split-Path` with no optional parameters strips off anything starting with the last `\`, it can be used for this particular scenario. See [Split-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-6) for more information.